# how to find nearest equal or higher multiple of ten in python

Tags: python, rounding, floor, ceil

I have a this [small task](http://www.gs1.org/how-calculate-check-digit-manually) , where I am rounding up the number to higher multiple of ten. But want to round it to nearest multiple of ten.

**My code :**

```
import math

a = map(int,list(str(7990442)))
b = map(int,list(str(1313131)))
print "a :",a
print "b :",b

l= []
for p,q in zip(a,b):
    l.append(p*q)
print "prod list :",l
ls = sum(l)
print "sum :",ls
def roundup(x):
    return int(math.ceil(x / 10.0)) * 10
top = roundup(ls)
print "round value: ",top
val = top-ls
print "val :",val
a.append(val)
print "output :",a
```

**Output :**

```
a : [7, 9, 9, 0, 4, 4, 2]
b : [1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1]
prod list : [7, 27, 9, 0, 4, 12, 2]
sum : 61
round value:  70
val : 9
output : [7, 9, 9, 0, 4, 4, 2, 9]
```

**Expected Output :**

```
sum : 61
round value:  60
val : 1
output : [7, 9, 9, 0, 4, 4, 2, 1]
```

Comment: How should edge cases like 65 or 75 be handled? Do you want them consistently rounded up, consistently rounded down or some other variation?

Comment: @Tagc Yes If number  = 65 it should be rounded up to 70

Comment: Do you want all numbers midway between two multiples of ten to be consistently rounded up then? e.g. 65 -> 70, 75 -> 80?

Comment: Yes for all middle number(5) they must be rounded up and even I need to adjust the val number to be positive only, In my case it should in range(0-9)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `round(x / 10.0) * 10` instead of `math.ceil`.

Even easier would be

```
def custom_round(x):
    return int(round(x, -1))
```

This immediately rounds to a multiple of ten.

Comment: Note that because of the way `round` works, this implementation will produce some possibly unexpected results: `custom_round(65) = 60`, `custom_round(75) = 80`. Not sure if this matters to OP.

Comment: That is actually a very good point, I've been 'burned' by IEEE rounding rules before. For those who don't know: the rule is to round to the nearest _even_ number: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Rounding_rules This is meant to prevent statistical bias in large samples.

Answer (score 3):

For the general purpose, given a `base` to round to:

```
def my_special_round(x, base=10):
    return int(base * round(float(x)/base))
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the smallest multiple of ten, I would do something like this. This way I didn't need to use Math Lib:

```
while True:
    n=int(input("number"))
    n=n/10
    n=int(n) # it removes decimal
    n=n*10 #then by make it times 10 to return to proportion
    print(n)
```

In this code I used the `int` casting to get rid of the unit.

If you want to find the nearest (including the top one) you could use an `if` unit is more than 5, then add one:

```
while True:
    n=int(input("number"))
    if (n%10>5):
        n=n+10
    n=n/10
    n=int(n)
    n=n*10
    print(n)
```